# DataTable Total Row Server Side

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, datatables, yajra-datatable

I'm trying to add the total row in [datatable yajrabox](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/) using **server side**
In the code below, I return [query builder](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/engine-query) to the datatable because it is much faster to deal with big data with millions of row

```
use DB;
use DataTables;

$result = DB::table('table')->select('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8', 'column9', 'column10', 'Group', 'Login', 'time_msc')
                ->whereBetween('time_msc', [$fromDate, $toDate])
                ->where(function ($result) use ($finalItem) {
                    foreach ($finalItem as $keyword) {
                        // $query->where('Group', 'like',  '%' . $keyword . '%');
                        /*->where('Login', '=',  $keyword);*/

                        if (is_numeric($keyword)) {
                            //Debugbar::info($keyword . " number");
                            $result->orwhere('login', '=',  $keyword);
                        } else {
                            //Debugbar::info($keyword . " string");
                            $result->orwhere('group', 'like',  '%' . $keyword . '%');
                        }
                    }
                })->latest('deal');
        
 return Datatables::of($result)->toJson();
```

I cannot use the collection because the **result more then 500,000** rows it will be very slow.

Also, I cannot use  [datatable API to add total in footer](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) it sum only the first 10 rows

**Is there any way to add the total for column1, column2 and column3 in the new row in query builder?**

Example

[image]

Using [laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x)

Comment: with millions of records. calculating total will again takes 5-10 seconds. So why not use Js to add the total in table from front end? Once the data is rendered.

Comment: @PushkrajJori In the front end it calculates the displayed rows only but I want all

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer [here](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2821) I use [Adding response with closure](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/response-with#closure)

```
$column1= number_format($result->get()->sum('column1'), 2);
$column2= number_format($result->get()->sum('column2'), 2);
$column3= number_format($result->get()->sum('column3'), 2);
            $total = array("column1" => $column1, "column2" => $column2, "column3" => $column3,);
        
            return Datatables::of($result)->with('extraDataTotal', function() use ($total) {
                     return $total;
            })->toJson();
```

In the front end, I display the total in the **[table footer](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html)**

```
 "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
                    var api = this.api();                 
                    $(api.column(0).footer()).html('Total');
                    $(api.column(12).footer()).html( settings.json.extraDataTotal.column1);
...
 }
```

Comment: This is gonna take more than 500mb of ram. Not good in production.

Comment: @PushkrajJori if use ```$result->get()->sum('column1')``` without getting it will be faster but not that match Is there any other way to sum a column that has more than 7 million rows?

Comment: when you use get() you fetch all the data from database to ram and then you are doing calculations on that collection in the ram instead of database which is worst use case when it comes to large data. You should do all the calculations in the database. If you share the actual queries with actual column names i might be able to help you build that query in eloquent.

Comment: @PushkrajJori The query I use is already in question, but I use query builder ```DB``` not eloquent because there is no relationship, from what I know query builder is faster than eloquent

Comment: @PushkrajJori you mean using ***stored procedure*** in database side?

Comment: Yes, here is a example of how I calculate billions of records at once.

Comment: $listStats = Cache::remember('remember_key', 600, function () use ($id) {
            return ModelName::selectRaw("count(CASE WHEN `column_name` = '1' THEN 1 END) as count_column_name")
            ->selectRaw("count(CASE WHEN `column_name` = '2' THEN 1 END) as count_column_name")
            ->selectRaw("count(CASE WHEN `column_name3` = '1' THEN 1 END) as count_column_name3")
            ->selectRaw("count(CASE WHEN `column_name2` = '1' THEN 1 END) as count_column_name2")
            ->where('where_key', $id)
            ->firstOrFail();
        });
You can use this approach for sums.

Comment: @PushkrajJori Thank you a lot, The way you provide it works much faster.